# div (table-cell) does not expand when width is set to 100%

Tags: html, css-tables

I convert table element to all divs, but div of  element does not expand like colspan="5" when width attribute is set 100%. How to make it expands full width? How to expand full width 2nd row?

[image]

```
<style>
    .table {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;          
    }
    .tr {
        display: table-row;   
        width: 100%;         
    }
    .td {
        display: table-cell;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        border: black solid 1px;
    }
</style>



<div class="table">
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td">Product</div>
            <div class="td">Unit Price</div>
            <div class="td">Quanity</div>
            <div class="td">Total Points</div>
            <div class="td">Temp</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td">
                <span>Serial Number</span>
                <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
                    <input maxlength="50" name="serialNo" id="serialNo" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is tabular data, use a table.

Comment: He has own reason for using `div`.

Comment: As Alexdn said, I have to use div instead of table element. I think about Bootstrap framework, gridview responsive. Maybe, it can solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use table-layout: fixed:

```
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%; 
  table-layout: fixed;         
}
```

Also, I would recommend you to use `<table>` instead of `<div>` in the tabular form.

Comment: this cause all table cells in a row to take equal width - which doesn't look like what the OP wants (see the image)

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue is that I have to div instead of table element